# how to make your bot send more than one direct embedded messages on discord

Tags: discord.js

I'm new to coding and to be honest sometimes i don't know what i am doing, i try looking for videos online but i cant find the right answer or i don't get what they are trying to say.I hope someone can tell me what to do or what i am doing wrong in this coding.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const colors = require("./colors.json");

const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});

const token = 'my token';

const PREFIX = '!';


bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online!`)
    bot.user.setActivity("Live chat", {type: "HELPING"}); 
})

bot.on("message", async message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

      if (message.author.bot) return;


      if (message.content.startsWith ("!Help") || (message.content.startsWith ("!help"))){
        let uEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colors.blue)
        .setTitle("**Hello there Human how can i help you today?**")
        .addField('**1. If you need help or have an issue with a purchase please type**', '**Purchase**')
        .addField('**2. If you need help or have an issue with Impulse mod please type**', '**Impulse**')
        .addField('**3. If you need help or have an issue with GTA V Game key please type**', '**GTA V**')
        .addField('**4. If you need help or have an issue with Spotify Premium Key type**', '**Spotify**')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(`Live chat bot | At your service`, bot.user.defaultAvatarURL)
        message.author.send({embed: uEmbed})

    }

    if (message.content.startsWith ("Purchase") || (message.content.startsWith ("purchase"))){
        let uEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colors.aqua)
        .setTitle("**Our bot is not ready for this command**")
        .addfiled ("please creat a ticket on the **#『』support-ticket chennel** in the Knight-Shop Server and staff will be in touch with you shortly.")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(`Live chat bot | At your service`, bot.user.defaultAvatarURL)
        message.author.send({embed: uEmbed});
    }

})

bot.login(token);
```

```
(node:3864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value).setColor(...).setTitle(...).addfiled is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should learn the base language first before using a framework / API, in this case you made a simple typo, `addfiled` instead of `addField` like you did above

Comment: hey thanks mate i did fix the typo and i figured out what else i was missing thanks.